# Приложение под android на c++

Tags: android, c++

Ребята, всем привет! Я изучаю C++ всего лишь полгода и у меня вопрос! Как написать приложение под android на С++? Вообще возможно ли это? Или мне лучше не стоит париться и просто переходить на java. Если всё же можно написать на С++,то распишите прям план действий, что нужно делать(что читать), потому что я не смог ничего дельного найти.(желательно с ссылками) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На моб. приложения обычно учат Java или Kotlin  для Андройдов или Swift под IOS. Чтобы на С++, честно, не слышал - нужно гуглить

Comment: С полу годами знакомства с С++ лучше конечно не париться и переходить на java. Написание пользовательских приложений на андроид совсем без java по факту невозможно, так как большая часть системных API имеет java интерфейс. Взаимодействие с ними со стороны C++ посредством jni - то еще удовольствие.

Comment: в теории всегда можно найти фреймворк на плюсах типо кокоса, но это не совсем чистое.